# Can you make a form object work for new and edit actions if the form itself is never persisted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object, oop, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a form object work for `new` `User` and `edit` `User` actions. The form object creates or updates a `User` through it's `save` method, but the form object itself is never persisted so Rails always tries to make a POST even though I'm specifying different routes in the `simple_form_for` url.

Is there any way to make it work for both actions?

*UsersController.rb:*

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
  def new
    @user_form = UserForm.new(account_id: current_account.id)
  end

  def create
    @user_form = UserForm.new(user_form_params)
    if @user = @user_form.save
      flash[:success] = "User created"
      redirect_to admin_user_path(@user)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user_form = UserForm.new(existing_user: @user, account_id: current_account.id)
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_form_params)
      flash[:success] = "User saved"
      redirect_to admin_user_path(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

*UserForm.rb*

```
class UserForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :email

  def initialize(params = {})
    super(params)
    @account = Account.find(account_id)
    @user = existing_user || user
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.new do |user|
      user.fname = fname
      user.lname = lname
      user.email = email
    end
  end
    
  def save
    @user.save
    @user
  end
end
```

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_form, url: (@user.present? ? admin_user_path(@user) : admin_users_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :fname  %>
    <%= f.input :lname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.submit %>
    
end
```

The new/create flow works fine, but editing an existing `User` returns

```
No route matches [POST] "/admin/users/69"
```

Comment: If you look at the answer I gave you to your previous question it actually fixes this.

Comment: @max Sorry I asked again but I thought I had explained myself wrong. Could you explain what the `to_model` method does? It did fix the routing problem indeed

Comment: On normal models `to_model` just returns self. When you pass a record to `form_for` or `link_to`  the polymorphic routing helpers call `to_model.model_name.route_key` or `singular_route_key`  depending on if the model is `persisted?`.  Passing `[:admin, @user_form]` will cause the polymorphic route helpers to use `admin_users_path` instead of just `users_path`.  https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UserForm
  # ...

  def to_model
    @user
  end
end
```

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_form, url: [:admin, @user_form] do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :fname  %>
    <%= f.input :lname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.submit %>
end
```

When you pass a record to `form_for` (which SimpleForm wraps), `form_with` or `link_to` the polymorphic routing helpers call `to_model.model_name.route_key` or `singular_route_key`  depending on if the model is `persisted?`.  Passing `[:admin, @user_form]` will cause the polymorphic route helpers to use `admin_users_path` instead of just `users_path`.

On normal models `to_model` just returns self.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html